# Phabricator: run unit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, phabricator

I want to write a custom Unit Test for Phabricator.

For that purpose, I checked out the documentation for [Writing Unit Tests in Phabricator](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/unit_tests/) and created a file at `./phabricator/src/infrastructure/testing/testcase/PhabricatorTrivialTestCase.php` (for using the trivial phabricator test case) with the following content

```
class PhabricatorTrivialTestCase extends PhabricatorTestCase {

  private $two;

  public function willRunOneTest($test_name) {
    // You can execute setup steps which will run before each test in this
    // method.
    $this->two = 2;
  }

  public function testAllIsRightWithTheWorld() {
    $this->assertEqual(4, $this->two + $this->two, '2 + 2 = 4');
  }

}
```

When I try to run it, I get the following message.

```
$ cd ./phabricator
$ arc unit src/infrastructure/testing/testcase/
No tests to run.
```

Why can't I run the test as documented? Is there some step missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out the solution.

A few things had to be done.

- moved the test file to the directory `./src/extensions/__tests__` (the folder has to be `__tests__`)
- renamed class `PhabricatorTrivialTestCase` to `SomePhabricatorTrivialTestCase` (because test with name `PhabricatorTrivialTestCase` already exists)
- run `arc liberate` (to make `SomeTrivialPhabricatorTestCase` available for testing)
- commit changes
- run `arc unit --everything` (because `arc unit` returns "No tests to run", but `arc unit --everything` works